# Which One Of the Following Force or Forces?

Tags: grammar, indian-english

Recently I have been given an exam. There was a multiple choice question(technical engineering question). There were four options and out of four only one was correct.

Each option had the particular force of fluid mechanics written.

Question was like

> Which one of the following force will dominate

Now my question is:

Is the above sentence correct and meaningful according to standard written English? Or should it rather be

> Which of the following forces will dominate.

For clear understanding of whole question I am attaching full Picture of official question.

[image: Click here to see the picture of the question]

Comment: you can see the picture of the question.. as it is written which of the following force..  they are referring to four forces given in the question

Comment: Please see updated answer. The text is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo in the question. It is missing the plural `s`

> Which one of the following force**s** will dominate?

is how to ask the question to get one force as answer.

I do not, however, see any way to challenge the question. It is clear despite the typo, that the answer is the "one dominating force"

Comment: Sir, please can you tell me that the way they have given in question is right or wrong.. is there is any meaning of the whole question,, i can challenge this question to the IIT giving reason that it is meaning less question and grammatically incorrect.

Comment: The sentence in the text should be `Which one of the following forces will dominate?` with a plural forces. Regardless.

Comment: so i must go ahead and contest this question.. can you please provide me the explanation that I should upload in support of my challenge. thanks

Comment: I cannot give you a legal foundation. The question is completely clear regardless of the typo. They want ONE of the forces A,B,C,D

Comment: PS: Where is the laminar flow?

Comment: @cocgame1 Since *you* gave the exam, you shouldn't need to contest the question - just exclude it from your marking scheme if you think your students might have been disadvantaged by the wording. (If you were a student for this exam, you'd have *sat* or *taken* the exam instead.)

Comment: Are you sure `I have given an exam` was not supposed to be `I have been given an exam`

Comment: No i am a student.. i want marks for this question

Comment: i was the student for this this exam,, unfortunately i marked wrong option,, so i am trying to get marks in this way of proving this question as meaningless.

Comment: It isn’t. Sorry. Very clear despite the typo.